# How to run wp_remote_get() inside of a loop for multiple page API response?

Tags: wp-remote-get

I am using [wp_remote_get()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_remote_get/) to grab some JSON from an API call. Everything is working great except that the API I am using has a limit of 100 results per response and there are just over 300 results that I need to loop over. You can get additional pages by adding `&page=2`, `&page=3`, etc. to the API URL. How would I go about refactoring this code in order to check each page of results and append the results of each page to an array?

```
$page = '1';
$url = 'https://example.com/products&page=' . $page;
$results = array();
$request = wp_remote_get($url, $args);
if (!is_wp_error($request)) {
    $data = wp_remote_retrieve_body($request);
    $body = json_decode($data);

    foreach ($data as $datapoint) {
        array_push($results, $datapoint);
    }

    ++ $page;
    // Run additional wp_remote_get on next page
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm reading the docs right, [`wp_remote_get()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_remote_get/) will return a `WP_Error` on failure, but not necessarily on a 404/400/403 (etc) status code from your remote server. (Though that will depend in part on what your remote server sends back if there's an invalid request.)

You can check the status code using [`wp_remote_retrieve_response_code()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_remote_retrieve_response_code/).

I'd use something like this:

```
$page = 1;
$results = array();
$url = 'https://example.com/products&page=' . $page;
$keep_going = true;
while ( $keep_going ) {
    $request = wp_remote_get( $url, $args ); // This assumes you've set $args previously
    if ( is_wp_error( $request ) ) {
        // Error out.
        $keep_going = false;
    }
    if ( $keep_going ) {
        $status = wp_remote_retrieve_response_code();
        if ( 200 != $status ) {
            // Not a valid response.
            $keep_going = false;
        }
    }
    if ( $keep_going ) {
        $data = wp_remote_retrieve_body($request);
        $body = json_decode($data);

        foreach ($data as $datapoint) {
            array_push($results, $datapoint);
        }

        ++ $page;
        // URL for the next pass through the while() loop
        $url = 'https://example.com/products&page=' . $page;
    }
}
```

This code is *untested* and probably inelegant, but it should provide a decent starting point for you. If you're unclear on `while()` loops, check the [PHP docs](https://www.php.net/while).

Comment: This is a perfect starting point, thank you so much!